# How to find a list of 100 elements of the intersection of 3 large sets?

Tags: python, algorithm, set

Is there any way of avoiding to calculate the intersection of all 3 sets and then slicing the first 100 numbers?

My code so far is:

```py
def intersection_alg():
    get_set_from_variable = [A,B,C]
    cfs_set = set()
    for logical_name in get_set_from_variable:
            tmp_set = set(get_list_from_db(logical_name))
        cfs_set = cfs_set.intersection(tmp_set) if cfs_set else cfs_set
    return list(cfs_set)[:100]
```

Comment: first 100 numebrs from intersection of all 3 sets

Comment: typo error it's intersection

Comment: Your code isn't indented properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generator and `itertools.islice`, see the example below. Depending on what you know about the content of your sets, you may be able to improve performance by changing the order in which you iterate in the `for` loop.

The exact result may differ between runs, as sets are iterated in arbitrary order.

Playground: https://ideone.com/hMBZIw

```py
import itertools


def lazy_intersection(*sets):
    for x in min(sets, key=lambda s: len(s)):
        if all(x in s for s in sets):
            yield x


a = {2*k for k in range(1000)}
b = {3*k for k in range(1000)}
c = {5*k for k in range(1000)}

generator = lazy_intersection(a, b, c)

first_10 = list(itertools.islice(generator, 10))
print(first_10)
```

Output (note that the ascending order is not guaranteed):

```
[0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270]
```

---

Resources:

- [docs.python.org: itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)
- [docs.python.org: itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)
- [wiki.python.org: Generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)